# How to play audio files into the microphone input with Adobe Flash Plugin (linux Fedora 20)

Tags: linux, audio, flash, alsa, pulseaudio

I have Linux, Fedora 20 OS out of the box with PulseAudio abstraction layer on top of ALSA layer, all things just out of the box and work OK.

### The Quest Is to:

I want to broadcast my own preliminary created audio file (this is mandatory) and possibly my own real voice (this is optionally) to video chats which based on Flash Player Plugin.

Ideally, I want to mix my own voice with my lovely audio tracks in background on chatr0uletеe service.

So, in another words I need to fake microphone input (or to fake it AND to mix it with my real voice coming from the real microphone).

### False Victory Of Mine.

I had solution for PulseAudio fully compatible (ONLY!) application like VLC and Skype. 
The solution base on so-called PulseAudio's "sink", you just have to create one with:

```
# pactl load-module module-null-sink
```

Starts VLC playing, Starts Skype call and go to

```
# pavucontrol
```

GUI interface to redirect VLC output toward created "sink", and Skype input from the same "sink". I also able to mix my own voice with VLC output with PulseAudio's "sink" without a problem (ask me in private if needed).

### The Problem Is.

I went to http://www.onlinemictest.com/ (clicked «Microphone Test» section).
Then I grant flash access to my mic and camera to this site, then
went to Flash Player settings (not to global settings) with right mouse click
and select "mic" section. No PulseAudio's "sink" enumerated here.
So, browser Flash Plugin used underneath ALSA layer, not the PulseAudio one.